# ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'

Tags: python-3.x, stringio, pandas-datareader

I am trying to get data from yahoo of stocks of a company through the code. 
But i am getting an ImportError at pandas_datareader.data where is says 
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'
Please help 
I am new to this...and already spent 4 hrs but could not resolve.

I have even tried

```
import io 
from io import StringIO
```

still getting the same error..!!

```
import datetime as dt 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import style 
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web 



style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2018,12,31)

df = web.datareader('TSLA','yahoo',start,end)
print(df.head(5))
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JAILANCHAL\Desktop\tut.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader.data as web 
  File "C:\Users\JAILANCHAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "C:\Users\JAILANCHAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.av.forex import AVForexReader
  File "C:\Users\JAILANCHAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\av\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.base import _BaseReader
  File "C:\Users\JAILANCHAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import StringIO, bytes_to_str
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'
```

Comment: What versions of Python and pandas and pandas_datareader are you using? For me, I get an error here: `df = web.datareader('TSLA','yahoo',start,end)`.

Comment: I am using python 3.5.4 with pandas 0.25 and pandas_datareader 0.7. I am also getting the error at the same line of code.

Comment: If `from io import StringIO` works, you could perhaps try a different version of `pandas`, as it looks like the issue is with that package.

Comment: I switched to pandas 0.19.1 and pandas_datareader 0.6.0 . It has started working with just 'import pandas_datareader.data as web' . 'from io import StringIO' is no longer required. Also, I have come across that many the data sources have been  deprecated. But Quandl is working fine for me. Robinhood, morningstar, yahoo, google and even av didnt work for me. THANKS for help !!